# Proper thread safe using atomic_load

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I'm working in a c++ project and I'm came across with this doubt

I'm have this object that is access by many threads

`std::shared_ptr<const Node> local_node(std::make_shared<const Node>());`

When I want to read the Node I use:

`auto node = std::atomic_load(&local_node)`

And I want to modify the Node I copy the node and then modify the copy and finally I do a **atomic_storage** to the original node:

```
auto node = new Node(*std::atomic_load(&local_node));
node->foo = new_foo;
std::atomic_store(&local_node, std::shared_ptr<const Node>(node));
```

My question is, this approach is correct to do my Node thread safe? or there is the possibility of race condition doing this?

And when I a read the Node from **atomic_load**, it is safe read the attributes from my node??

```
auto node = std::atomic_load(&local_node)
auto copy_foo = node->foo;  //This is safe ??
```

Comment: You say "modify the node", but your code proceed to modify the *shared pointer*. Which one do you mean?

Comment: Yes i guess "modify the node" it was a wrong expression, i want to update the `std::shared_ptr<const Node> local_node` with the new node

Comment: Looks good to me. I don't see any data races, as defined in C++ language spec. Of course, you should realize that, if two threads do the read-modify-write simultaneously, it's unpredictable which version ends up stored in `local_node`. Similarly, `copy_foo` may be obsolete by the time you use it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ok, thanks so much!